# Creating lesser partitions while sending more messages

Tags: apache-kafka

If we create a partition of 3(bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic my-topic --partitions 3) while creating topic and if the producer sends 10 messages,How will those 10 messages get stored in topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create 3 partitions to a topic, those 10 messages you are sending will be distributed across 3 partitions of the topic you created.

Make sure you fully understand the behavior of topics and partitions in Kafka and how are messages distributed. Here is a where you can start http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction